# How to loop through and edit certain elements of a nested list?

Tags: r

I'd like to reference and edit a varying number of elements in a nested list like this:

```
# example:
a <- list()
a$var1$var11 <- 101
a$var1$var12 <- 102
a$var2$var21 <- 201
a$var3$var31 <- 301
str(a)



# output
#List of 3
# $ var1:List of 2
#  ..$ var11: num 101
#  ..$ var12: num 102
# $ var2:List of 1
#  ..$ var21: num 201
# $ var3:List of 1
#  ..$ var31: num 301
```

But let's say that the list is much larger, and with a varying size everytime it's made. How can I loop through every `var1`, `var2`, check if the name *is* exactly `var2`, and then change the value in `a$var2$var21` from `201` to something else?

I've tried this:

```
for (elem in str(a)){
  print(elem)
  if(elem==var2){
    print(elem)
  }
}
```

This *seems* to be running fine, but the output is:

```
List of 3
 $ var1:List of 2
  ..$ var11: num 101
  ..$ var12: num 102
 $ var2:List of 1
  ..$ var21: num 201
 $ var3:List of 1
  ..$ var31: num 301
```

And what I'd really like to do is using `elem` to subset parts of the list so that `elem` would replace `var1` in `a$var1$var11` like this `a$elem$var11` and the output would be `num 101`

I suspect I'm approaching this thing in a wrong way, but I just don't know what different approach I should pursue. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: You are looping over the structure of 'a'

Comment: you could something like `do.call(rbind,a)` to restructure your data

Comment: Could there may be multiple list entries called `var2`? If not, maybe this is enough `modifyList(a, list(var2=list(var21 = 1000)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do

```
for(nm in names(a)) if(nm == 'var2') a[[nm]][[1]] <- 'new'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you want to do with replacement logic.  But thought I would offer up at least an alternate syntax you might find easier to work with from `purrr`

```r
library(purrr)
# example:
a <- list()
a$var1$var11 <- 101
a$var1$var12 <- 102
a$var2$var21 <- 201
a$var3$var31 <- 301

a
#> $var1
#> $var1$var11
#> [1] 101
#> 
#> $var1$var12
#> [1] 102
#> 
#> 
#> $var2
#> $var2$var21
#> [1] 201
#> 
#> 
#> $var3
#> $var3$var31
#> [1] 301


# with pluck you can use either strings or numeric index
pluck(a, "var1", "var11")
#> [1] 101

# I think you want to iterate over every single list item?

for(elem in seq_along(a)) {
  for(subelement in seq_along(pluck(a, elem))) {
    print(pluck(a, elem, subelement))
    mytarget <- pluck(a, elem, subelement)
    if(mytarget == 201) {
      pluck(a, elem, subelement) <- 999
      cat("Replacment made\n")
    }
  }
}
#> [1] 101
#> [1] 102
#> [1] 201
#> Replacment made
#> [1] 301
a
#> $var1
#> $var1$var11
#> [1] 101
#> 
#> $var1$var12
#> [1] 102
#> 
#> 
#> $var2
#> $var2$var21
#> [1] 999
#> 
#> 
#> $var3
#> $var3$var31
#> [1] 301
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>